# AFNetworking 2 + SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, alamofire

`SwiftyJSON` https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON looks really promising. However, the instructions only talk about integration with `Alamofire` (AFNetworking for Swift). However, due to the nature of the current project, it's already using `AFNetworking2` and cannot switch to `Alamofire`. However, I'm having trouble integrating `AFNetworking` with `SwiftyJSON`.

I have the following block of code, how do I convert `responseObject`, which can be downcasted to `NSDictionary`, to a JSON object as defined in `SwiftyJSON`? The code below doesn't work.

```
        let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = AFHTTPSessionManager.GET(
            url,
            parameters: params,
            success: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    // How do I convert responseObject, which can be downcasted to NSDictionary to a JSON object?
                    let data = JSON(data: responseObject)
                    completion(task: task, response: data as JSON!, error: nil)
                })
            },
            failure: { (task: NSURLSessionDataTask!, error: NSError!) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    completion(task: task, response: nil, error: error)
                })
            }
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I thought I was the only one having trouble with JSON parsing in AFNetworking and SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to dispatch to the main queue. AFNetworking already calls these blocks on the main thread.

The initializer you're using is expecting data, not a JSON object.

You're currently using this initializer, which expects an `NSData`:

```
let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
```

Instead, you should be using this initializer:

```
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
```

SwiftyJSON will work fine if you pass `responseObject` here.

---

One other note: this code doesn't belong in the completion blocks. In AFNetworking's design, you should be creating a response serializer that handles the server's response. I recommend looking at the source for `AFJSONResponseSerializer` and porting that over to use SwiftyJSON.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I removed the dispatch_async block from within `success` and `failure`. I've also delayed calling `JSON(object: jsonObject)` and that seemed to work. Thanks!